# UITableView reloadRows only works every other time

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom UITableView ('table') fed by a data array (e.g. 'rowVals[]') which does not display correct values after making a data change.

**Error Case**

1. Init table to 5 rows with values fed by 'rowVals' = ["R1" - "R5"]

   - post - displays correctly
2. Change rowVals[1] from "R2" to "S2"

   - post - shows init values (e.g. w/"R2")
3. Call table.reloadRows() on the table

   - post - shows new values (e.g. w/"S2")
4. **(BUG!)** Call table.reloadRows() on the table

   - post - shows init values again! (e.g. w/"R2")
5. Steps #3/#4 now cycle repeatedly!

**Question**

Why is this occurring, where is the table finding "R2" to display? I have spent over two hours debugging this to no avail, yikes! Thoughts?

Comment: I can post example code, let me know if useful. Stepping out of the weeds for a moment and taking a deep breath, less is more for the moment!

Comment: Why did a user mark this as ‘-1’? Please provide feedback for question improvement if possible! :)

Comment: Probably because you haven't shown any code. You should show your `cellForRowAt` as a minimum, plus show where you reload the table and how that code is triggered.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Paulw11, I dove back in and got to a working solution! I will apply and post resolution tomorrow, thank you for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestion Paulw11, with debugging and persistence I was able to resolve and correct this.

**Problem Source**

- Custom cells, initialized on viewDidLoad() in vc

**Problem Solution**

- Have *tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath)* return the cell directly, not by dequeueReusableCell()

I am not sure entirely why this corrected to problem but it does somewhat make sense, dequeueReusableCell() returns a new cell when the 'identifier' is not found!